# perl regexp for multi line file

Tags: regex, perl

i have patterns in a file which looks like this:

```
 db::parameter nf
      -data.          Value.        \
      -data2.         Value2.     \

 db::parameter ww
      -data1.         Value1.        \
      -data2.         Value2.        \
```

I need regexp which will take whole pattern into a variable starting from `db`

I tried to match the pattern untill empty line will show up

```
     while(<$infile>){
                chomp;
                If( $_=~/db:parameter\s+$){
                            print $_;}
```

P.s. I know regexp is totaly wrong, but im not that good at regexps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an empty line as a record separator, may I suggest using [paragraph mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24/)?

```
$/ = "";        # set input record separator to empty string
while (<>) {    # proceed as usual
```

Using the empty string is a special case, as described in the documentation linked above:

> Setting $/ to "\n\n" means something slightly different than setting to "" , if the file contains consecutive empty lines. Setting to "" will treat two or more consecutive empty lines as a single empty line. Setting to "\n\n" will blindly assume that the next input character belongs to the next paragraph, even if it's a newline.

Comment: @mpapec Normally I would suggest that, but I don't know the context, perhaps there are other loops.